# How to parse file datetime in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to convert a text string like this - `Dec 15 21:44` into a date/time format in excel (Polish version).

I tried `=DATEVALUE` function but without success.

Comment: This is too vague to give a indicative answer. What exactly are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: @Raystafarian I put exact my input it is `Dec 15 21:44` I do not have a year in it.

Comment: @CharlieRB I would like to convert this text to format in which Excel recognize this string as date

Comment: @Raystafarian I hope now it is clear

Answer (score 1):

You will need a formula. Say your text is in cell F2. Then in G2 you can use -

`=DATE(,MONTH(1&LEFT(F2,3)),DAY(MID(F2,5,2)))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(F2,5))`

Set a custom format of that cell to something like - `mmm dd h:mm;@`

The main issue is the text (letters) date, hence the need for the formula. I don't think there's a custom format that will take text and convert it to a date value, so we trick it with `month(1&left(F2,3))`. At least that's how it works for me on Excel 2007 English.

Comment: It's worth noting two things: 1) Garath will have to decide what to use for a year value or this formula will default to `0` which is `1900`. 2) This formula works even if it's a one-digit day or a 3-digit time so kudos on robustness, even if it was accidental.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the field in Excel like a date, and pick your preferred format for whichever cell holds the date.

I have succesfully tested that `Dec 15 21:44` is converted into `01-12-2015 21:44` when being pasted into a cell (I am using european date format, by the way) by Excel, which can then in turn be converted into:

```
01-12-2015         (short date format)
1. december 2015   (long date format)
21:44:00           (time)
```

by applying the normal format selectors in Excel.

Obviously the conversions rely on your selected locale, so if you're using US english, you will get something like:

```
12-01-2015         (short date format)
December 1st 2015  (long date format)
09:44:00 PM        (time)
```

Comment: In my Excel it doesn't work. I have Polish settings